How To Create Linear Progress Bar With Curved Circles?
I’m trying to recreate a smooth curved progress bar with circular nodes similar to this.

What I'm Trying to Achieve:

A progress bar that has a continuous, smooth curve connecting each node.
The nodes (circles) are seamlessly integrated into the curve, without simply overlaying them on top of a rectangular progress bar.
The curved effect between the nodes should be visually smooth and natural.

What I’ve Tried:

Drawing a horizontal rectangle and overlaying circles at fixed points.
Using SwiftUI Path to attempt to curve the connections between the circles.

However, overlaying circles on a rectangle does not produce the desired smooth curve between the nodes. It looks disconnected and flat rather than integrated.
Requirements:

Answers can be language-agnostic. While I’m working in SwiftUI, I'm open to explanations or examples in any language or framework (e.g., HTML/CSS/JS, React, Flutter).
The focus should be on the geometry or drawing logic required to achieve the seamless curve.

Any help with understanding the mathematical or graphical approach to building this style of curved node progress bar would be greatly appreciated!

I would think a custom Shape (which creates a Path) should be possible here. Path has different functions to choose from for adding curves and a mix of these might be the best approach. Please show the code for what you tried already.

Path is the way to go, but how to make the correct path is the question.
